# Google calendar migration to version 3

Tags: asp.net, google-calendar-api

I am developing my app on Google calendar migration from version 2 to version 3 in ASP.NET. The refresh token that we had in version 2, now i am unable to use the same refresh token in version 3. Can any one please guide me why i am getting this problem. As per the Google calendar documentation, one account should have only one refresh token so what would be the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OAuth scope has changed between [v2](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v2/developers_guide_protocol#AuthOAuth) and [v3](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v2/developers_guide_protocol). Thus you'll need to get a new refresh token by going through the authorization process again with the user.